# Cassandra create pool with hosts on different ports

Tags: cassandra, port, connection-pooling, host

I have 10 Cassandra Nodes running on Kubernetes on my server and 1 contact point that expose the service on port 10023.

However, when the datastax driver tries to establish a connection with the other nodes of the cluster it uses the exposed port instead of the default one and i get the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [/10.210.1.53:10023] Pool was closed during initialization
```

Is there a way to expose one single contact point and have it to communicate with the other nodes on the standard port (9042)?

i checked on the datastax documentation if there is anything related to it but i didn't find much.

this is how i connect to the cluster

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
        builder.addContactPoints(address)
                .withPort(Integer.valueOf(10023))
                .withCredentials(user, password)
                .withMaxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds(600)
                .withSocketOptions(
                        new SocketOptions()
                                .setConnectTimeoutMillis(Integer.valueOf(timeout))
                                .setReadTimeoutMillis(Integer.valueOf(timeout))
                ).build();
        Cluster cluster = builder.withoutJMXReporting().build();
        Session session = cluster.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

After driver contacts first node, it fetches information about cluster, and use this information, and this information includes on what ports Cassandra listens.

To implement what you want to do, you need that Cassandra listened on the corresponding port - this is configured via `native_transport_port` parameter of the `cassandra.yaml`.

Also, by default Cassandra driver will try to connect to all nodes in cluster because it uses DCAware/TokenAware l[oad balancing policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/). If you want to use only one node, then you need to use `WhiteListPolicy` instead of default policy.  But is not optimal from the performance point of view.

I would suggest to re-think how you expose Cassandra to clients.

Comment: "After driver contacts first node, it fetches information about cluster, and use this information, and this information includes on what ports Cassandra listens."
it correctly detects what the other nodes on the cluster are, as it tries to establish the pool connection with every other node of the cluster, however while the ip is correct, the port remains the one that is publicly exposed (10023) instead of the intranode one.

are you suggesting i should set the listen port to the 10023 for every node?

Comment: not `listen_port` - it's used for internal communication, but `native_transport_port` - it's used by drivers, etc.

Comment: The fact is that Kubernetes maps the port 10023 to the 9042, that is, the service handles it correctly for one node, but then fails as it looks for other nodes on that port

Comment: As I mentioned, you can try to use `WhiteListPolicy` to route traffic through one node