# Trino with cassandra connector is trying to connect to the contact points with the wrong ports

Tags: cassandra, datastax, trino

I'm using Cassandra connector and want to connect Trino to three nodes (contact points), all nodes use 19001 port, Trino successfully connect to the first one (using 19001 port), but not to the other two.

```
connector.name=cassandra
cassandra.contact-points=192.168.144.56,192.168.144.57,192.168.144.55
cassandra.load-policy.dc-aware.local-dc=datacenter1
cassandra.native-protocol-port=19001
cassandra.client.connect-timeout=1m
cassandra.client.read-timeout=1m
cassandra.retry-policy=BACKOFF
cassandra.username=xxxxx
cassandra.password=xxxx
```

Logs say:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.pool.ChannelPool  [s0|/192.168.144.57:9042]  Error while opening new channel (ConnectionInitException: [s0|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.17.0, CLIENT_ID=...}): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException))
```

Note that Trino (or the datastax driver) is trying to connect to 192.168.144.57 via 9042.

I tried adding the other ports in this way:
`cassandra.native-protocol-port=19001,19001,19001`
But it isn't correct.

I would expect Trino to connect to the other nodes using port 19001.

Comment: I have found that this issue could be relate to Cassandra, not Trino + Cassandra.
[cassandra-create-pool-with-hosts-on-different-ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372326/cassandra-create-pool-with-hosts-on-different-ports?rq=2)